# Prevent string duplicates with Redis

Tags: redis

Is there any correct way to prevent the insertion of duplicates with Redis?

I'm trying to store several strings and both the key **and** the string needs to be unique. I would like to get Redis to **refuse** to create the string if its value or its key already exists.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to maintain key-value pairs {k1=>v1, k2=>v2, k3=>v3...} such that {k1, k2, k3...} is obviously unique and {v1, v2, v3 ...} is also unique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess there should be several ways.

Does uniqueness have to be on the scope of one pair of key/value? i.e. is it alright to have the same *value* several times, each one associated to a different key?

If so, one of the simpler ones (but as always - it really depends on your use case and the amount of key/value pairs you need, read/write ratio etc.) is this:

Use keys of type `SET`. Each key will only contain one value (member) instead of the usual usage of sets to hold, well, sets.

That way, whenever you try to create a key that its name exists already, Redis will refuse. Whenever you try to create a value to a given key where that value already exists as a member of the key's set, Redis will refuse as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Unfortunately, I'm trying to make sure that each value and key can't be inserted twice. Do you have any natural way around this with Redis?

Comment: Maintain a different `SET` of all values. Then, whenever you add a new entry, first add the value to that set and if it fails that means the value already exists. If it succeeds, add your key+value (this time as plain Redis string key/value). If that fails, that means the key already exists, and then you should delete your value from the `SET` you inserted it to before.

Answer (score 4):

You can first use [EXISTS](http://redis.io/commands/exists)  command to check if a key exists and then determine if  value in the set exists using [SISMEMBER](http://redis.io/commands/sismember) command and then insert the key value pair.